# Searching for a file from when I select a row in a DataGridView using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in Windows Forms using C#.

I am currently working on a project where I want to be able to select a row from my datagridview (DGV), and from that selected row try to locate a CSV file from a folder.

For example if I select a row from my first DGV the programme should automatically recognise that the cell in column 4 is the folder directory name of where the CSV file is located in my documents, and when that row is selected it automatically displays the csv file in the second DGV.

Any help would be a appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more precise where you are stuck?

Comment: please show the current code you have which depicts exactly where you are stuck ..Relevant code is always good.. if you are expecting us to do your work for you then that's not a good expectation on your part.. show what you have tried

Comment: I think he wants to catch click on datagridview

Comment: Trying to make a good start on it. I have been searching the web trying to find information to be able select a row from a DGV and from the selected row use cell 4 to show the Document Directory Information. The names of cell 4 reference directory names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Attach handler to DataGridView.CellMouseClick Event [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseclick.aspx)
2. Get row index from DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs argument.
3. Get data from column 4 inside clicked row
4. Open file and put all data inside second DGV

Comment: Thanks. I am just slightly confused how to start thats why I was brief. much appreciated.